# windows 7 mapped drive visibility problem

Tags: windows-7, mappeddrive

I just installed Windows 7 RTM on my developer machine. Right after the installation I added my domain account to local administrators group and added the machine to company's domain.

We use local folder mapped as a network drive to store dll's that we reference. The drive is created by:

subst S: "D:\DllFolder"

The drive mapped ok, however the following issue occured:
When I tried to open a solution using Visual Studio 2008 it told me that I needed to run it as administrator to be able to use the asp.net projects hosted on IIS.
I run VS as administrator and the solution opened fine but that VS instance could not see the S: drive.

Can anyone tell me how can I work around that problem?
(The temporary solution that works is to disable the UAC, but that is not acceptable in the long run.)

Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subst is user specific, you need to run subst as administrator as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, .NET is very sensitive to permissions while running on a non-local drive. It can detect that even "through" the `subst`. You might be better served by mapping the drive directly:

```
net use s: \\server\path\to\DllFolder
```

But I doubt that will help.

You would be better served by doing the development locally (on your local drive) and synchronizing your work to the central location. Either using a source-control program (like [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/)), or just copying.